# Platform specific code error: MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send an Notification in Flutter, so I set up my platform specific code (only Android) but I get the following error back:

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send_notification on channel reminderChannel)
```

I already cleaned the project but still not working.

Future to invoke method:

```
const platform = const MethodChannel("reminderChannel");

Future<void> invokeMethod() async {
  try {
    //FIXME Missing plugin
    int testValue = await platform.invokeMethod("send_notification");
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {}
}

invokeMethod();
```

mainActivity:

```
private static final String notificationChannel = "reminderChannel";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), notificationChannel).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
                    if (methodCall.method.equals("send_notification")) {
                        System.out.print("Android Method called");
                        result.success(5);
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

I want that the testValue variable in invokeMethod equals 5.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: did it print here? -> System.out.print("Android Method called");

Comment: System.out.print("Android Method called") is not printed out.

Comment: does yout MainActivity.java (Android) contain a call to GeneratedPluginRegistrant asking it to register itself?

Comment: Yes, please check my updated question.

Comment: try changing the channel name to something different like this "reminder_channel"

Comment: Still the same problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your channel is deallocated at the end of the method.

So keep a reference to the MethodChannel in your acivity:

```
private static final String notificationChannel = "reminderChannel";
private MethodChannel mainChannel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    reminderChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), notificationChannel)
    reminderChannel.setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
                    if (methodCall.method.equals("send_notification")) {
                        System.out.print("Android Method called");
                        result.success(5);
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't assign a variable to the new MethodChannel. How did you make this?

Comment: That is right, I missed that. Updated my response, please recheck.

Comment: Still the same problem